# Sanitize PHP textarea in WP metabox allowing HTML markup

Tags: php, html, wordpress, sanitization, meta-boxes

In a Wordpress site I have a custom textarea metabox with text editor.

If I use `sanitize_textarea_field()` to sanitize the text, the HTML markup manually set in the text editor disappears.

If I use `wp_kses_post` HTML tags are allowed.

Is this the right solution to keep a good security level?

Thank you.

Comment: wordpress have own filter for sanitization please check the documentation at codex

Answer (score 2):

Yes, wp_kses_post() is a right method as per the WP documentations.

1. [Securing (sanitizing) Input](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-input/#sanitizing-the-data)
2. [Securing (escaping) Output](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-output/#escaping)

And when we need control over the allowed HTML tags and attributes, we can use [wp_kses()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/).

Comment: Updated link for [Sanitizing data](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/sanitizing/), [Escaping data](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/escaping/)